# How can I extract ARGB from a Color and convert them to byte components?

Tags: java, android

I'm working in Java/Android and I want to take the `0xFFFFFFFF` int color and break it into 4 bytes for red, green, blue and alpha. I know `Color` has methods for extracting specific color values, but it gives them as an `int`. I've gone through the SDK and found that the `Color.red(color)` method is the same as saying `(color >> 16) & 0xFF`, honestly I have no idea what this means but I think I can use this in some way.

I've tried doing

```
byte red = (byte)Color.red(color);
```

but this doesn't seem to work. The whole point is so I can feed in the values into OpenGL with the method

```
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 4, myColors);
```

myColors being a byte[].

Any help/tips/points would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If Color has methods for extracting specific color values then extract Red as int and make it Hex then Green then Blue. You might also want to extract alpha. with `Integer.toHexString(int)` you can print the Hex value of an int.
`(color >> 16) & 0xFF` positions the Red color (by bitshifting and adding) to the first 2 out of 6 hexdigits of a non alpha Color. non alpha Color RBG consists of 3 bytes of information. Every byte is one Color with the order R(Red) B(Blue) G(Green) . 0xFF is one byte, if set to Red means that the Color has full red etc etc

Comment: I understand that it consist of bytes, but I am having problems with splitting it into 4 bytes (argb). Is there no other way besides turning the int into a string and then back to a byte? That just seems like way more work than should be needed.

Comment: try bitshifting all the colors like red